# PHP glob() only get the first or last 3 files

Tags: php

I am trying to use PHP's glob() to get the first or last 3 files from the directory sorted by name. Is this possible? Similar to what MySQL does with LIMIT.

I know I can read all the files first then filter it out later, like:

```
$aDir = glob($sDirPath . '/*.txt'); // <--- IS THERE A WAY TO LIMIT HERE?
foreach( $aDir as $key => $file ) {
    ....
}
```

But I don't think it make sense to read for example 10,000 files in the directory to get only the first or last 3 files, wasting server resource.

Thank you.

Comment: First 3 = `ls -l | grep '\.txt$' | head -3`, or Last 3 = `ls -l | grep '\.txt$' | tail -3`

Comment: @Glavić - well yes and no. `tail` still requires that all the files are listed. At one level or another, the whole list of files will have to be considered, especially if there is need for a specific order.

Comment: @grebneke: then `ls` has probably some kind of sorting mechanism, where `head -3` can always be used

Comment: @Glavić: yes, but it would still be going through all items to produce the sorted output. But sure, it might be faster than loading it all into PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is [readdir()](http://php.net/readdir). However, you state

> the first or last 3 files from the directory

which implies there is some kind of order. To have order, the items must be sorted. To be sorted, all items must be considered. So it looks as if all 10000 files will have to be checked at one level or another - either in PHP or at the filesystem level.

`readdir` returns the files in the order they are stored by the filesystem. You could read the first three entries matching `*.txt` and then quit. To get the "last" files, you would have to read through the whole list. That is if you are happy with the order `readdir` gives you.

Answer (score -2):

Use array_slice it's even simpler, this should do the trick :

```
$i = 0;
foreach(array_slice(glob($sDirPath . '/*.txt'), 0, 3) as $key => $file ) {
    if($i == 3)
        break;
    ....

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Then have a look at opendir and readdir to get the entries one by one ;)

Comment: glob() will read all the files in a given directory and thats how it is, if you want something else then can check   DirectoryIterator
http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php